# Issues with Software Sources

Tags: installation, software-sources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software on an old now unsupported Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version)

I just got a problem with software installation and software sources on my Ubuntu.

I cant use Application manager to install anything:

> Could not download all repository indexes
>   The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted... .

Also if I go to `software sources`>`Select Best Server`>`Choose the best server`, then it wants me to reload and then again gives me the same problem.

I do have Internet connection and my Ubuntu version is 9.04.

Comment: I suggest you to upgrade Ubuntu. 9.04 is too old to be answered by the users I think.

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-on-an-old-now-unsupported-ubuntu-version

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 9.04 reached end of life nearly two years ago on October 23 2010, as [this article](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2010-September/000137.html) describes, so you have had no security updates for a long while. This probably should be a concern by now.

**However**, even though this is the case you can probably still use the `old-releases` part of of the [Ubuntu site](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/) and replace the entries in your `sources.list` with the old-releases urls; i.e. use `old-releases.ubuntu.com` instead of `archive.ubuntu.com`. There is more at the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720421) on this topic of keeping old versions going.
Please see this [official Ubuntu article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) on end of life upgrades too as that explains quite a lot about the process of adapting your `sources.list`.

So, there is a way to keep using Jaunty, but I do advise an upgrade soon.

Answer (score 0):

## This should probably help....

(but this answer won't work for a long time!)

Enter this command on terminal:

> **sudo software-properties-gtk**

Software Sources window will come up. Under the **"Ubuntu Software"** tab, choose **"Other.."** inside **"Download From"** drop down menu.

[image]

Then select this as your download server :

> ## New Caledonia
>
> **achive.ubuntu.nautile.nc**

[image]

**Reload** the package index (or **sudo apt-get update**), and thing should work fine.
Most servers around the world are removing packages of old Ubuntu releases.

## I suggest you to upgrade Ubuntu!